# How to scale videoZoomFactor at same velocity of pinch

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a `UIPinchGesture` to adjust the `videoZoomFactor` of the iPhone camera. I want it to zoom in at the same velocity that my fingers move apart. I'm using the following code inside the gesture recognizer handler:

```
let pinchVelocityDividerFactor: CGFloat = 35
var error: NSError
let device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.deviceInput!.device
do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        let desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor + atan2(pinchRecognizer.velocity, pinchVelocityDividerFactor);
        // Check if desiredZoomFactor fits required range from 1.0 to activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor
        device.videoZoomFactor = max(1, min(desiredZoomFactor, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor))
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
}
catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        print(error)
}
```

At the moment, the rate relies on the pinchVelocityDividerFactor. How would I adjust this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the ratio of the distance between your fingers after they've moved, over the distance of the previous move needs to be added on to the videoZoomFactor. This ratio also needs to be multiplied by the zoom factor to keep the scaling even as you zoom in (otherwise you're gonna be having to pinch a lot when you're zoomed in a lot). Code below.

```
func handlePinchToZoomRecognizer(pinchRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if pinchRecognizer.state == .Began {
            if (pinchRecognizer.numberOfTouches() >= 2) {

            oldFinger1 = pinchRecognizer.locationOfTouch(0, inView: previewView)
                oldFinger2 = pinchRecognizer.locationOfTouch(1, inView: previewView)
                oldDistance = hypot(oldFinger1.x - oldFinger2.x, oldFinger1.y - oldFinger2.y)
            }
        }
        else if (pinchRecognizer.state == .Began || pinchRecognizer.state == .Changed) {
            if (pinchRecognizer.numberOfTouches() >= 2) {
                let newFinger1 = pinchRecognizer.locationOfTouch(0, inView: previewView)
                let newFinger2 = pinchRecognizer.locationOfTouch(1, inView: previewView)
                let distance = hypot(newFinger1.x - newFinger2.x, newFinger1.y - newFinger2.y)
                var error: NSError
                let device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.deviceInput!.device
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    let desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor + device.videoZoomFactor*(distance/oldDistance - 1)
                    print(device.videoZoomFactor*(distance/oldDistance - 1))
                    // Check if desiredZoomFactor fits required range from 1.0 to activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor
                    device.videoZoomFactor = max(1, min(desiredZoomFactor, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor))

                oldFinger1 = newFinger1
                oldFinger2 = newFinger2
                oldDistance = distance
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            }
            catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```